# To what extent is build.phonegap.com cross platform?

Tags: cordova, mobile

By the description on their homepage build.phonegap.com looks like you could develop the app for IOS using Xcode then somehow submit it to build.phonegap.com and it will give you a build for all mobile platforms.

Is that correct? Is it that easy? If not, please explain.

What if I'm using a plugin for IOS such as [the ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser), will it still work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just make sure you don't write any iOS specific code.

> Head over to https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins and scroll
>   down to the Childbrowser plugin. You will see that the plugin is
>   supported for the online build service. See my previous answer
>   regarding this topic and how to edit your config.xml file: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384252/phonegap-barcodescanner-sharing-plugin/15408997?noredirect=1#comment21811299_15408997)