# PhoneGap: BarcodeScanner Sharing Plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner, phonegap-build

Note:

1. I wanted to develop IOS and Android application with QR code scanning feature.
2. I do not own Mac machine, I'm using `Netbean`/`Eclipse` in WIndows OS.

---

**Question:**

1. Is it possible to have single codebase written with Eclipse Windows OS + android [BarcodeScanner Plugin](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/blob/master/README.md), and get built into IOS application via [Adobe Cloud Build service](https://build.phonegap.com/)

---

Deeply appreciated if someone could give me an advice.

Comment: You can also try with a libray named "ZBar", which is dedicated for QR code scanning.
The Android versoin of the library is here:
https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner

And the iPhone version is here:
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: So can I build the android version of ZBarScanner in IOS format? Because I do not have a mac machine to develop IOS application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the online compiler of phonegap ([Phonegap Build](http://build.phonegap.com)) then it's possible to use a plugin for all supported devices.

> Plugins : https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml
>
> In the Config.xml
>
> < gap:plugin >: specifies a PhoneGap plugin for PhoneGap Build to
>   include in your generated apps. At present, to include a plugin, you
>   will to ensure:
>
> the plugin is supported by PhoneGap Build; and any JavaScript script
>   tags are present in your index.html file. More details, including a
>   list of available plugins, are in our [plugins documentation](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins).

Goto https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins and scroll down to the BarcodeScanner plugin.

Comment: +1 Yes, this is the exact info I wanted to know :) Finally someone clarifies me :) Thanks alot @Mogipogi, appreciated for your detailed explanation :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this official Barcode Scanner plugin really has problems with some barcodes (not QR codes). Other than that, it works fine, especially with QR codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Barcode scanner plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner). You can reuse the hybrid part on ios. But some basic settings need to be done on ios as well. Try [Phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com/) if you want to build for multiple platforms easily.

Comment: You are telling me what I've already known. I'm asking is it possible to have single codebase written in Windows OS + android BarcodeScanner plugin, and get built into IOS via Phonegap Build Service?

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone:
https://github.com/zeroasterisk/PhoneGap-BarcodeScanner-Example-iOS

And specific to your question.

- All devices can share the same `www` (html/js/css) directory & sub-dirs
- All devices need their own unique PhoneGap application and codebase for device code

PhoneGap does the work of bridging the two, the shared WWW codebase, and the device-specific native code.